# Parse json response android retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to parse response from server in Android studio.
But I am not getting all values in Arraylist.

I have created ItemData.java and  ItemResponse.java

I am Calling Api using getItemData Method:

```
public void getItemData() {
        Call<ItemDataResponse> call = service.getData(token, "200");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemDataResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ItemDataResponse> call, @NonNull Response<ItemDataResponse> response) {

                Log.d("dataFromServer", response.body.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ItemDataResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                progressDoalog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(LiveVehiclesActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is Json response:

```
{
   "code":"1",
   "items":[
      {
         "item_id":"200",
         "speed":"2"
      },
      {
         "item_id":"201",
         "speed":"0"
      }
   ]
}
```

ItemsResponse.java:

```
public class ItemDataResponse implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("code")
    private String code;

    @SerializedName("items")
    @Expose
    private List<ItemData> items;



    public String getResponsecode() {
        return responsecode;
    }

    public void setResponsecode(String responsecode) {
        this.responsecode = responsecode;
    }

    public List<ItemData> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ItemData> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

ItemData.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ItemData {

@SerializedName("item_id")
@Expose
private String itemId;
@SerializedName("speed")
@Expose
private String speed;

public String getItemId() {
return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
this.itemId = itemId;
}

public String getSpeed() {
return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(String speed) {
this.speed = speed;
}

}
```

After run in debug mode I am getting response like:

```
code:"1"
items=null
```

Comment: Your class generation looks good, but perhaps your response is not well formatted, try receiving response body instead of response, and print that response body and see if there is an issue with response format.

Answer (score 1):

your should modify

```
class ItemData {
    private String item_id;
    private String speed;

    public String getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public String getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(String speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ItemData model does not seem to be consistent with the JSON response.
i.e

```
{
    "item_id":"200",
    "speed":"2"
}
```

should map to:

```
class ItemData implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("item_id")
    private String itemId;

    @SerializedName("speed")
    private String speed;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SerializedName attribute for the field contains "_". Here for item_id in your ItemData class getting problem in mapping.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ItemData {

@SerializedName("item_id")
@Expose
private String itemId;
@SerializedName("speed")
@Expose
private String speed;

public String getItemId() {
return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
this.itemId = itemId;
}

public String getSpeed() {
return speed;
}

public void setSpeed(String speed) {
this.speed = speed;
}

}
```

please change your ItemDataResponse class also

```
public class ItemDataResponse {

@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("items")
@Expose
private List<Item> items = null;

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

public List<Item> getItems() {
return items;
}

public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
this.items = items;
}

}
```

Comment: please change your ItemDataResponse  class also as above.